# Celery workers NOT ACKing after task completion

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Issue

- I am creating an **empty-ish task** on celery
- Using RMQ as broker
- **After task completion, celery is NOT ACK-ing the RMQ message**
- Thus, worker is unable to pick new tasks
- As soon as I restart RMQ pod, everything becomes normal and new tasks start getting ACKed
- I tried using multiple versions of RMQ, tried upgrading celery as well
- Also, this was not a problem in lower versions of celery/kombu (3.x)

Note

- **Problem only happens when am doing things on K8s**
- When I run a RMQ docker container and test celery worker running natively on my computer, things work fine (versions are same)

Versions

- Celery version : 4.4.7
- Kombu version : 4.6.11
- RabbitMQ version : 3.8.16

Celery entry point

```
celery = Celery()
celery.config_from_object(celeryconf)
```

Celery task

```
class EmptyTask(celery.Task):
    name = 'empty_task'

    def run(self):
        logger.info("###############################################################")
        logger.info("I AM AN EMPTY TASK")
        logger.info("***************************************************************")


celery.tasks.register(EmptyTask())
```

Celery conf

```
BROKER_URL = amqp://testuser:**@rabbitmq:5672//
BROKER_USE_SSL = False
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True

CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True # IN NEED THIS CONFIG
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1 # IN NEED THIS CONFIG

CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
celery_queue_names = 'test_queue'.split(',')
queue_args = {'sync': {'x-max-priority': 255}}
CELERY_QUEUES = [
    Queue(q, routing_key=q, queue_arguments=queue_args.get(q))
    for q in celery_queue_names
]
```

Script to start worker

```
#!/bin/bash

QUEUES="test_queue"
exec celery -A testceleryworker.tasks worker -l INFO -Ofair --hostname=${QUEUES//,}@%h --queues=$QUEUES
```